# Laurent expansion of the tangent function about a given point

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am given the following question :

> Show that if $\tan z$ is expanded into a Laurent series about $z = \pi/2$,
>
> (a) the principal part is $-1/(z - \pi/2)$,
>
> (b) the series converges for $0 < |z - \pi/2| < \pi/2$,
>
> (c) $z = \pi/2$ is a simple pole.

Once parts (a) and (b) are solved, part (c) will follow immediately, but I am not getting any idea on how to expand the function about the given point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, please use Math-Jax to formulate your questions in the future. Makes them a lot easier to read.

Comment: Take a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1324309

Answer (score 2):

By using a [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Reflections) of the $\tan$ function, all we need is its expansion at $0$.

Let $w=z-\pi/2$, then
$$\tan(z)=\tan(w+\pi/2)=-\frac{1}{\tan(w)}=-\frac{1}{w+O(w^3)}=-\frac{1}{w}\cdot \frac{1}{1+O(w^2)}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think O(w^n) means some term which has w raised to the power of n. But how do I proceed using this?

Comment: This is the Big O-notation,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Infinitesimal_asymptotics In our case $O(w^2)$ is power series which starts with $cw^2$.